# NoClassDefFoundError after renaming a package

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror

I am writing a simple application using Netbeans; on creating a new Java project I renamed the automatically created package from `oldpackage` to `newpackage` using Netbeans' rename function (ie using Refactor > Rename...)

When I run the program I get this exception:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oldpackage/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oldpackage.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: oldpackage.Main.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

I've done some Googling but couldn't find an obvious fix - can anyone help?

Comment: Try cleaning and build the project again. If the problem persists try make a search inside files for the oldpackage

Comment: Cleaning and building was the first thing I did

Comment: If you are just clicking a button to run the program, try looking in run configurations or setup to make sure your project and main class are correct/updated.

Comment: Thank you Ryan the run configuration was set to the old package

Answer (score 0):

Change the package name `applicationId` in the gradle file. Clean and Reopen your Project

Answer (score 0):

Some things you have to check. Those are :

1. Check Package name of your app from menifest.xml and build.gradle both file.
2. Check manifest activity name with full path. If activity path is incorrect then correct it.
3. If problem not solved then execute **File--> Invalidate Cache / Restart** . Hope problem will solved.
4. If problem not solved then delete build folder and rebuild the project. Now your problem will solved.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a `libGDX` project on `Android Studio` and I wanted to rename a package folder from **lowercase** to **CamelCase** and I refactored everything, however I was not able to start the project without issues until I deleted the build folder located in the project:

`core/build`

Answer (score 0):

If working on intellij idea IDE then navigate to **Run -> Edit Configuration**
Replace the new package name with existing one in **Build and Run** area
and in below Code Coverage area deselect the older package name and insert your new package name then **Apply** and **Ok**
After this you will be able to run your project successfully.

Image attached for reference

[image]